# Google apps script no longer writes data to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using the HTML service in combination with Google Apps script for a long time to write data to a Google spreadsheet. I never had any problems, until halfway this month. The data was no longer written to my Spreadsheets. I was able to solve the problem by republishing the web app. I do not wish to encounter this in the future because i have lost a lot of data.

How can I prevent this in the future? 
Is this something to do with rights?
Have things changed that I am not aware of?

Extra Information:

- The HTML app is executed by me
- And anyone even anonymous persons has access to the webapp

Below the piece of code that suddenly is no longer executed correctly:

`

```
function insertRow(registratie, config)
{
  registratie.tijdstip = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1" ,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
  //
  MailApp.sendEmail("My mail address",
                    config.schoolcode,
                    JSON.stringify(registratie));
  //
  try{
  //
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(config.IDss).getSheetByName("reacties");
  //
  // Er wordt gecontroleerd of er reeds een ingave is
  if (findID(ss,registratie)==false)
  {
    ss.appendRow([registratie.tijdstip, registratie.klas, registratie.voornaam, 
                  registratie.naam, registratie.email, registratie.maaltijden.toString(),registratie.maand, registratie.jaar, registratie.id, registratie.alternatief ]);
    //
    setNumberFormatReactieToString(ss);
  }
   //
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    //
     MailApp.sendEmail("My mail address",
                    'Probleem met warme maaltijden app voor school' + config.schoolcode,
                    JSON.stringify(registratie));
    //
    Logger.log(e);
    return e
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Hi! Without seeing the code, or even better, a [mcve], any answers to this question would have to be best guesses. Google is constantly making changes to the Apps Script platform, so there could be any number of updates that broke your code. Can you please edit your question to include the code that is not working for you?

Comment: Thx for your reply. I've added the piece of code that isn't executed correctly.

Comment: Your code looks fine and it's working again, if it ever happens again, I recommend you to contact [G suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)